# Как узнать глубину рекурсии?

Tags: javascript, node.js

как узнать глубину рекурсии или как реализовать эту программу:
Написать для Node.JS функцию, которая рекурсивно выводит список всех файлов и папок и их размер:
например:
dir1 (1000kb)
— subDir1 (500kb)
——— subFile1 (300kb)
——— subFile2 (200kb)
— subDir2 (500)
——— subFile1 (500kb)
вот уже немного готовый скрипт, сам написал:

```
const fs = require('fs');


function scaner(y,counter = 1){
    let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
    for(let x of y1){
        let stat = fs.statSync(y + x);
        if(!stat.isFile()){
            let path = y + x + '/';
            console.log(`${counter}` + x);
            scaner(path,counter++);
        }
    }
}
scaner('./');
```

Comment: Большая часть проблем должна бы решиться заменой `counter++` на `counter + 1`. Хотя не уверен, что все.

Comment: это одно и тоже

Comment: А вот тут, мсье, вы заблуждаетесь. Попробуйте.

Comment: @deebov `counter++` - пост инкремент. Оно +1 делает после вызова метода. То есть, вы, по сути, могли написать `scaner(path,counter);` ничего бы не изменилось.

Comment: @Suvitruf вот только там `for`, а `counter` локален для всего вызова, то есть и для цикла целиком. И от этого будет эффект.

Comment: @D-side в этом плане да, но я к тому, что при первом проходе цикла каждый раз тоже самое отправляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function scaner(y,counter = 1){
//Попробуй добавить тут counter++;
    let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
    for(let x of y1){
        let stat = fs.statSync(y + x);
        if(!stat.isFile()){
            let path = y + x + '/';
            console.log(`${counter}` + x);
            scaner(path,counter++//или тут ++counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Человек интересуется, как ему **внутри итерации** понять **текущую глубину рекурсии**, чтобы сделать в выводе соответствующий отступ.

Comment: Я бы добавил комментом, но нельзя добавлять еще просто.

Comment: Просто исходный текст ответа не имел никакого отношения к проблеме. Условие завершения рекурсии у автора уже есть, отсутствие в папке других папок. Как комментарий он тоже был бы бесполезен :)

Comment: counter++ поставил в начале функции,работает,но как, в чем разница?

Comment: смотри, когда ты используешь counter++ при передаче в метод, то переменная сразу передастся, а увеличится только когда придет возврат из функции, поэтому counter++ в начале метода сразу увеличивает переменную. По идее ++counter тоже должен работать так как он сразу увеличивает переменную, а потом передает

Comment: @D-side мой косяк, не правильно понял вопрос, да и в js не особо шарю)